# Render penrose staircase from multiple angles

Tags: 3d

I was wondering if it was possible to render the penrose staircase from any given angle, and if so, if it's possible to render a moving camera viewing the staircase. Also, how would you render the staircase assuming that you know the position and angle of the camera? I know this would require adjusting not only the model, but the staircase itself (via a break of some sort). Is this even possible?

Comment: Well it's possible: http://www.cse.ust.hk/~pang/papers/Impossible_Figures_ToG.pdf . I just don't know how to implement it.